Function onEllipticalArc in Snapper not working
If the dwg contains elliptical arc geometries, some functions are not recognized or work incorrectly.
For example function createEllipticalArcGeometry works with Vector3, but return Vector2.
Then apllyMatrix4 is calculated over the vertices, which ends up with NaN values (because 'z' is undefined).
Next, we are going to create a snapCandidate using makeEllipticalArc, but such a function does not exist (fromEllipticalArc exists).
Is it possible to fix this?
Thanks
